# Change CTRL button in Terminal commands

Tags: terminal, keyboard, macos

I am using a Macbook Air Mid 2012 with Sierra.

I am using a lot the terminal to run my local server etc. To cancel the local server I need to press CTRL + C. Unfortunately the CTRL button stopped working.

1) I think it's a mechanical issue, because sometimes it works. I already removed the key and tried to clean it but no success. Any other ideas in terms of making it work again?

2) My main question is: how can I move the CTRL + C command to another key. I would like to quit the server with the ESC key. Where can I change this? Is this a setting on the server (Rails Puma) or a Terminal setting?

Comment: [how can I redefine the interrupt signal to Escape or Delete key?](https://superuser.com/questions/310418/how-can-i-redefine-the-interrupt-signal-to-escape-or-delete-key) and [key bindings table?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116614/86436) > using the escape key is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could remap your modifier keys. In System Preferences, choose Keyboard, and click on the Modifier Keys ... button on the Keyboard tab. There, you can (for instance) have <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> act as your <kbd>Control</kbd> button.

[image]